# Copy optimizer statistics - Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, statistics

I am trying to copy statistics from one schema to another. I use the following commands but on the destination schema num_rows on the all_tables view remains unchanged. Is there any view that I can check on the destination schema that verify that statistics movement?

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.create_stat_table('DBASCHEMA','STATS_TABLE');
EXEC DBMS_STATS.export_schema_stats('APPSCHEMA','STATS_TABLE',NULL,'DBASCHEMA');
EXEC DBMS_STATS.import_schema_stats('APPSCHEMA','STATS_TABLE',NULL,'DBASCHEMA');
EXEC DBMS_STATS.drop_stat_table('DBASCHEMA','STATS_TABLE');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting and importing into the same schema.  If you want to copy statistics from APPSCHEMA to DBASCHEMA, this will work:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.create_stat_table('DBASCHEMA','STATS_TABLE');
    DBMS_STATS.export_schema_stats('APPSCHEMA','STATS_TABLE',NULL,'DBASCHEMA');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE DBASCHEMA.STATS_TABLE SET c5 = ''DBASCHEMA''';
    COMMIT;

    DBMS_STATS.import_schema_stats('DBASCHEMA','STATS_TABLE');
    DBMS_STATS.drop_stat_table('DBASCHEMA','STATS_TABLE');
end;
/
```

I changed the import to use DBASCHEMA.  The `UPDATE` in the middle is necessary to avoid the error `ORA-20000: no statistics are imported`, as explained by the My Oracle Support document 1430225.1.

Comment: Thank you jonearles. The missing was on updating the C5 column.